# In CMake, how to run dependencies or targets in order?

Tags: build, cmake

I'm migrating my current Makefile project to CMake, and I have a problem with achieving a similar effect from Makefile when one rule can execute multiple rules in a given order. Let's say I have four rules:

1. all
2. prepare
3. program
4. lock

Sometimes I want to run each of them separately, but I also want to have another rule called: **release**, that simply executes all four rules in a specific order. This is trivial in Makefile:

```
release: all prepare program lock
```

I had played with `add_custom_target` in CMake, and I came up with the following:

```
add_custom_target(prepare
        COMMAND ...)

add_custom_target(program
        COMMAND ...)

add_custom_target(lock
        COMMAND ...)

add_custom_target(release DEPENDS ${TARGET} prepare program lock)
```

I expected CMake to traverse dependencies in order, so it should build my target, and then run these three additional targets. However, it runs them completely randomly. I'm aware of possibility of creating a chain of `add_dependencies` commands, but this is ugly, and I also don't want to create unwanted dependencies between independent targets.

How can I run dependencies in order OR at least execute my custom targets through one command?

Comment: Why do you want them to run in order if they don't depend on each other?

Comment: They don't depend in terms of project or files, but, for example, if I run `lock` then I can't run `program` rule anymore. Yet sometimes I want to run `lock` by hand, for testing purposes. I used to invoking `make lock` and this was fine.

Comment: Custom targets can be built using e.g. `cmake --build . --target prepare`.

Comment: I don't get. In makefile `release: all prepare program lock` would run them in parallel too.

Comment: @KamilCuk It looks like processing dependencies from left to right is unwritten rule of `make`. People suggest to avoid relying on this behaviour, but I've never seen a situation where `make` processed dependencies paralelly. Maybe I'm that lucky.

Comment: Really? If I run `make -j 4` I expect `all prepare program lock` to be executed in parallel.

Comment: @KamilCuk This is an exception, because you manually tell how many jobs can run simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

In CMake, custom targets can have multiple commands. Unlike dependencies which can be paralellized, multiple command are run in order

From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> `COMMAND`
>
> Specify the command-line(s) to execute at build time. **If more
>   than one `COMMAND` is specified they will be executed in order**, but
>   not necessarily composed into a stateful shell or batch script. (To
>   run a full script, use the `configure_file()` command or the
>   `file(GENERATE)` command to create it, and then specify a `COMMAND` to
>   launch it.)

So to add your `release` target, you can specify all the commands to run:

```
add_custom_target(release
    DEPENDS ${TARGET}
    COMMAND ...
    COMMAND ...
    COMMAND ...
)
```